# firefox bypasses dnsmasq

Tags: dns, firefox, dnsmasq

Appears that Firefox does not use system's dnsmasq for dns resolution.
Chrome on the other hand does.

System's dnsmasq process is caching results, so it's easy to verify:

1. dig example.com - takes X ms
2. dig example.com - takes 0 ms (demonstrating it's cached)
3. open example.com in firefox - it takes 100+ms, ie is clearly not resolving via dnsmasq.

Does Firefox need explicit configuration to use host resolver?

FF network settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7BtL.png

Comment: How do you measure the time to resolve `example.com` in firefox?

Comment: @Isaac looking at `DNS Resolution` in devtools->network->timings